# Trying to get BarChart Works With Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, mpandroidchart

So I am trying to make BarChart works with Firebase. Currently, I am using **com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4** as the chart library.

I figured it out to load the chart, but after I updated the data, I get this error message saying that

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: One or more of the DataSet Entry arrays are longer than the x-values array of this ChartData object.
```

I have no idea how to make Firebase works with MPAndroidChart.

Below are the code.

**activity_history.xml**

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart 
  android:id="@+id/statistik_chart" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="550px"
  android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
```

**HistoryActivity.java**

```
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
private DatabaseReference referenceTicket;

public class HistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private String uid;
  private Long now_ms;
  private BarChart chart;

  private ArrayList < BarEntry > entries;
  private ArrayList < String > labels;
  private BarDataSet barDataSet;
  private BarData barData;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    uid = firebaseAuth.getUid();

    entries = new ArrayList < > ();
    labels = new ArrayList < > ();

    chart = findViewById(R.id.statistik_chart);
    String myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()) + " 23:59:59";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM");
    SimpleDateFormat format_tanggal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    Date date = null;
    try {
      date = sdf.parse(myDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    now_ms = date.getTime();
    referenceTicket = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("log");
    Query query_ticket = referenceTicket.orderByChild("created_date").endAt(now_ms);
    query_ticket.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int total_pengunjung = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        total_pengunjung_today.setText(String.valueOf(total_pengunjung));
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
    });

    labels.add("Jan");
    labels.add("Feb");
    labels.add("Mar");
    labels.add("Apr");
    labels.add("May");
    labels.add("Jun");

    try {
      String current_date_time = new SimpleDateFormat("2019-01-01", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()) + " 08:00:00";
      Date date_current = sdf.parse(current_date_time);
      Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(current_date_time);
      Calendar last_day_current_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      last_day_current_cal.setTime(convertedDate);
      last_day_current_cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, last_day_current_cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
      String last_day_current_string = format_tanggal.format(last_day_current_cal.getTime()) + " 18:00:00";
      Date last_day_current_date = sdf.parse(last_day_current_string);
      final long current_start_ms = date_current.getTime();
      final long current_last_ms = last_day_current_date.getTime();
      Query query_ticket_filter = referenceTicket.orderByChild("created_date").startAt(current_start_ms).endAt(current_last_ms);
      query_ticket_filter.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          int total_pengunjung = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
          int i = 0;
          AddValuesToEntry(total_pengunjung, i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
      });

    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
      String current_date_time = new SimpleDateFormat("2019-02-01", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()) + " 08:00:00";
      Date date_current = sdf.parse(current_date_time);
      Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(current_date_time);
      Calendar last_day_current_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      last_day_current_cal.setTime(convertedDate);
      last_day_current_cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, last_day_current_cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
      String last_day_current_string = format_tanggal.format(last_day_current_cal.getTime()) + " 18:00:00";
      Date last_day_current_date = sdf.parse(last_day_current_string);
      final long current_start_ms = date_current.getTime();
      final long current_last_ms = last_day_current_date.getTime();
      Query query_ticket_filter = referenceTicket.orderByChild("created_date").startAt(current_start_ms).endAt(current_last_ms);
      query_ticket_filter.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          int total_pengunjung = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
          int i = 1;
          AddValuesToEntry(total_pengunjung, i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
      });

    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
      String current_date_time = new SimpleDateFormat("2019-03-01", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()) + " 08:00:00";
      Date date_current = sdf.parse(current_date_time);
      Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(current_date_time);
      Calendar last_day_current_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      last_day_current_cal.setTime(convertedDate);
      last_day_current_cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, last_day_current_cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
      String last_day_current_string = format_tanggal.format(last_day_current_cal.getTime()) + " 18:00:00";
      Date last_day_current_date = sdf.parse(last_day_current_string);
      final long current_start_ms = date_current.getTime();
      final long current_last_ms = last_day_current_date.getTime();
      Query query_ticket_filter = referenceTicket.orderByChild("created_date").startAt(current_start_ms).endAt(current_last_ms);
      query_ticket_filter.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          int total_pengunjung = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
          int i = 1;
          AddValuesToEntry(total_pengunjung, i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
      });

    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
      String current_date_time = new SimpleDateFormat("2019-04-01", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()) + " 08:00:00";
      Date date_current = sdf.parse(current_date_time);
      Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(current_date_time);
      Calendar last_day_current_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      last_day_current_cal.setTime(convertedDate);
      last_day_current_cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, last_day_current_cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
      String last_day_current_string = format_tanggal.format(last_day_current_cal.getTime()) + " 18:00:00";
      Date last_day_current_date = sdf.parse(last_day_current_string);
      final long current_start_ms = date_current.getTime();
      final long current_last_ms = last_day_current_date.getTime();
      Query query_ticket_filter = referenceTicket.orderByChild("created_date").startAt(current_start_ms).endAt(current_last_ms);
      query_ticket_filter.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          int total_pengunjung = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
          int i = 1;
          AddValuesToEntry(total_pengunjung, i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
      });

    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
      String current_date_time = new SimpleDateFormat("2019-05-01", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()) + " 08:00:00";
      Date date_current = sdf.parse(current_date_time);
      Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(current_date_time);
      Calendar last_day_current_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      last_day_current_cal.setTime(convertedDate);
      last_day_current_cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, last_day_current_cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
      String last_day_current_string = format_tanggal.format(last_day_current_cal.getTime()) + " 18:00:00";
      Date last_day_current_date = sdf.parse(last_day_current_string);
      final long current_start_ms = date_current.getTime();
      final long current_last_ms = last_day_current_date.getTime();
      Query query_ticket_filter = referenceTicket.orderByChild("created_date").startAt(current_start_ms).endAt(current_last_ms);
      query_ticket_filter.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          int total_pengunjung = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
          int i = 1;
          AddValuesToEntry(total_pengunjung, i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
      });

    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
      String current_date_time = new SimpleDateFormat("2019-06-01", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()) + " 08:00:00";
      Date date_current = sdf.parse(current_date_time);
      Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(current_date_time);
      Calendar last_day_current_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      last_day_current_cal.setTime(convertedDate);
      last_day_current_cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, last_day_current_cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
      String last_day_current_string = format_tanggal.format(last_day_current_cal.getTime()) + " 18:00:00";
      Date last_day_current_date = sdf.parse(last_day_current_string);
      final long current_start_ms = date_current.getTime();
      final long current_last_ms = last_day_current_date.getTime();
      Query query_ticket_filter = referenceTicket.orderByChild("created_date").startAt(current_start_ms).endAt(current_last_ms);
      query_ticket_filter.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          int total_pengunjung = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
          int i = 1;
          AddValuesToEntry(total_pengunjung, i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
      });

    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  public void AddValuesToEntry(int val, int x) {
    entries.add(new BarEntry(val, x));
    barDataSet = new BarDataSet(entries, "12 Bulan");
    barData = new BarData(labels, barDataSet);
    chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    chart.setData(barData);
    chart.animateY(3000);
  }

}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: When you are adding entries are you adding values to labels? Because what I got from error message is that the size of both the arrays is not same. Insert break point before plotting graph and check size of arrays if they are equal or not.

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan thanks for your suggestion, but seems like I can barely understand what you suggest, can you gimme an example of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Remove following lines:

```
labels.add("Jan");
labels.add("Feb");
labels.add("Mar");
labels.add("Apr");
labels.add("May");
labels.add("Jun");
```

Change following code:

```
public void AddValuesToEntry(int val, int x)
{
    entries.add(new BarEntry(val, x));
    barDataSet = new BarDataSet(entries, "12 Bulan");
    barData = new BarData(labels, barDataSet);
    chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    chart.setData(barData);
    chart.animateY(3000);
}
```

To:

```
public void AddValuesToEntry(int val, int x)
{
    entries.add(new BarEntry(val, x));
    labels.add("insert label for each entry here respectively");
    barDataSet = new BarDataSet(entries, "12 Bulan");
    barData = new BarData(labels, barDataSet);
    chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    chart.setData(barData);
    chart.animateY(3000);
    chart.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Try the given code, the issue is with your labels, number of labels and entries you are providing to chart is not equal as I guessed. Moreover you are not adding line chart.invalidate(). This line let your chart know that dataset is updated with new values. Hope this helps do let me know if you need further assistance.